# zsh errors in dotfiles

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I am trying to set up a new work environment, using zsh and an old set of dotfiles. I have this error with git information and I do not know how to solve it. Here is the error from iTerm2 as soon as I cd into my dotfiles repo:

`~ ✔ cd dotfiles
_git_prompt_color:3: = not found
dotfiles ✔ _git_prompt_color:3: = not found`

I am assuming the issue surrounds line 3 of the `_git_prompt_color` method?
Here is the file where I think the issue is:

```
_git_prompt_info() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null)
  if [ -n $ref ]; then
    branch_name="${ref#refs/heads/}"
    branch_name_max_length=$(($COLUMNS/5))
    if [ ${#branch_name} -gt $branch_name_max_length ]; then
      echo "$branch_name[0,$(($branch_name_max_length-3))]..."
    else
      echo $branch_name
    fi
  fi
}

_git_status() {
  git_status=$(cat "/tmp/git-status-$$")
  if [ -n "$(echo $git_status | grep "Changes not staged")" ]; then
    echo "changed"
  elif [ -n "$(echo $git_status | grep "Changes to be committed")" ]; then
    echo "pending"
  elif [ -n "$(echo $git_status | grep "Untracked files")" ]; then
    echo "untracked"
  else
    echo "unchanged"
  fi
}

_git_prompt_color() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    current_git_status=$(_git_status)
    if [ "changed" == $current_git_status ]; then
      echo "$(_red $1)"
    elif [ "pending" == $current_git_status ]; then
      echo "$(_yellow $1)"
    elif [ "unchanged" == $current_git_status ]; then
      echo "$(_green $1)"
    elif [ "untracked" == $current_git_status ]; then
      echo "$(_cyan $1)"
    fi
  else
    echo "$1"
  fi
}

_color() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "%{$fg_bold[$2]%}$1%{$reset_color%}"
  fi
}

_separate()               { if [ -n "$1" ]; then echo " $1"; fi }
_grey()                   { echo "$(_color "$1" grey)" }
_yellow()                 { echo "$(_color "$1" yellow)" }
_green()                  { echo "$(_color "$1" green)" }
_red()                    { echo "$(_color "$1" red)" }
_cyan()                   { echo "$(_color "$1" cyan)" }
_blue()                   { echo "$(_color "$1" blue)" }

_full_path()              { echo "$(_blue "%~")" }
_working_directory()      { echo "$(_blue "%c")" }
_colored_git_branch()     { echo "$(_git_prompt_color "$(_git_prompt_info)")" }

_display_current_vim_mode() {
  if [[ $VIMODE == 'vicmd' ]]; then
    echo "$(_red "✘")"
  else
    echo "$(_green "✔")"
  fi
}

function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
  VIMODE=$KEYMAP
  zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select

function precmd {
  $(git status 2> /dev/null >! "/tmp/git-status-$$")
}

PROMPT='$(_working_directory)$(_separate $(_colored_git_branch)) $(_display_current_vim_mode) '
```

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`[` do not support the `==` operator. You've to either use `=` or perform the comparison using `[[` operator. `[` offers only limited functionality but it's POSIX compliant, While `[[` isn't.

Here it would be

```
if [[ "changed" == $current_git_status ]]
```

or

```
if [ "changed" = $current_git_status ]
```

- [Difference between test, [ and [[](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

**Tip** :

Try using `vcs_info` to obtain basic version control information.

- [`vcs_info` documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information)
- [`vcs_info` examples](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Misc/vcs_info-examples)